# Not getting subtotals when groups in R

Tags: r, group-by, subtotal

Every time a player changes I need subtotals of how many strikouts he had in his career.

I have tried doing it using the code below but was not getting subtotals.

```
player <- c('acostma01', 'acostma01', 'acostma01', 'adkinjo01', 'aguilri01', 'aguilri01', 'aguilri01', 'aguilri01', 'aguilri01')
        year <- c(2010,2011,2012,2007,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989)
        games <- c(41,44,45,1,21,28,18,11,36)
        strikeouts <- c(42,46,46,0,74,104,77,16,80)
        bb_data <- data.frame(player, year, games, strikeouts, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Here is code that did not work.

```
mets <- select(bb_data, player, year, games, strikeouts) %>% 
group_by(player, year) %>% 
colSums(SO)
```

Here is the output I would like to get:

```
player      games strikeouts
acostma01   130   134
adkinjo01   1     0
aguilri01   0     351
Grand Total       485
```

Here is what I was getting (tail of data):

```
player    team    year  games strikouts
<chr>     <chr>   <int> <int> <int>
swarzan01 NYN      2018    29    31
syndeno01 NYN      2018    25   155
vargaja01 NYN      2018    20    84
wahlbo01  NYN      2018     7     7
wheelza01 NYN      2018    29   179
zamorda01 NYN      2018    16    16
```

Comment: I am still having trouble getting the output to display properly. If someone can tell me what I am doing wrong I would much appreciate it.

Comment: @tmfmnk Thanks. What did you do?

Comment: Just slightly edited your post for better readability :)

Comment: @tmfmnk How did you do it? Did you add a certain number of spaces before each line of output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(tidyverse)

bb_data %>% 
  group_by(player) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(games, strikeouts), sum) %>%
  add_row(player = 'Grand Total', games = NA, strikeouts = sum(.$strikeouts))
```

This would give you:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  player      games strikeouts
  <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1 acostma01     130        134
2 adkinjo01       1          0
3 aguilri01     114        351
4 Grand Total    NA        485
```

Which is consistent with all values except `games` for `aguilri01` - I presume it is a typo, but let me know if this is incorrect.

For descending order, you could do:

```
bb_data %>% 
  group_by(player) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(games, strikeouts), sum) %>%
  arrange(-strikeouts) %>%
  add_row(player = 'Grand Total', games = NA, strikeouts = sum(.$strikeouts))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  player      games strikeouts
  <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1 aguilri01     114        351
2 acostma01     130        134
3 adkinjo01       1          0
4 Grand Total    NA        485
```

To also include the seasons played, you can try:

```
bb_data %>% 
  group_by(player) %>% 
  mutate(seasons_played = n_distinct(year)) %>%
  group_by(player, seasons_played) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(games, strikeouts), sum) %>% 
  arrange(-strikeouts) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  add_row(player = 'Grand Total', games = NA, seasons_played = NA, strikeouts = sum(.$strikeouts))
```

Comment: @It is a typo. Thanks for bringing it to my attention. I'm studying your code to understand how it works so well.

Comment: How can I get the strikeouts to appear in descending order?

Comment: Good to hear! Consider accepting and/or upvoting the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the year column begin summed, you can do that:

```
 library(data.table)
 data = setDT(bb_data)[, c(lapply(.SD, sum), .N), by =player]
```

`.N` allows you to count the number of rows by player (number of years).

Then you can order it (with a `-` to get it decreasing):

```
data[order(-data$strikeouts)]
```

You get this result:

```
1: aguilri01 9935   114        351 5
2: acostma01 6033   130        134 3
3: adkinjo01 2007     1          0 1
```

Comment: What I was really interested in with regard to the year column but did not include it in my problem writeup because I thought it might be complicated to do is to include in the output for each player how many seasons he played. For example, for adkinjo01 that would be one. Is that easy to do?

Comment: If you have a row by year, you can do this: `setDT(bb_data)[, .N, by =player] ` which counts the number of rows by player

Comment: How can I get the strikeouts to appear in descending order?

Comment: You can have both together directly with `setDT(bb_data)[, c(lapply(.SD,sum), .N), by =player] `

Comment: You can sort it afterwards, with the function `order`

Comment: When I tried to run your code in RStudio I got these errors:
> setDT(bb_data)[, .N, by =player]
Error in setDT(bb_data) : could not find function "setDT"
> library(data.table)
Error in library(data.table) : there is no package called ‘data.table’

Comment: You have to install the package `data.table` if you don't have it already (seems that you don't from the error message)

Comment: It seems that you cannot install the data.table package from within RStudio. I got the following message, so I will investigate this further on stackoverflow: install.packages(data.table)
Error in install.packages : object 'data.table' not found